# Choose other timezone when install Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, timezone

[image: screenshot]

Why can't I select English and choose timezone outside US?

Comment: Did you choose `en_US` as language ?

Comment: at first i choose english

Comment: Wasn't there a previous screen to select the region? That looks like a bug.

Answer (score 10):

If you cannot choose a language that better correlates to your location, just install with any timezone.  When the install is finished, as root, run the command `tzselect` to set a new timezone.  Also, consider filing a bug against the debian installer if you truly cannot pick your language and your timezone properly.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a bug**, please [report it](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) on the [debian-installer](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=debian-installer) package.

In the meanwhile, you just need to correct the timezone *after* the installation by using:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

or

```
# tzselect
```